# hiding row permanently in table

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I am using this code to display table

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th style="height: 25px">NAME</th>
            <th style="height: 25px">EMAIL</th>
            <th style="height: 25px">CELL NO</th>
            <th style="height: 25px">CITY</th>                   
            <th>Hide Candidate</th>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <?php
    while($data_set1 = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>{$data_set1['ename']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$data_set1['eemail']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$data_set1['ecell']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$data_set1['ecity']}</td>";

        echo "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"hide_cand\" id=\"hide_cand\" onclick=\" return hideRow(this)\"/></td>";
\"/></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    ?>
```

and using this javascript I am able to hide row of table temporarily ,how to hide it permanantly when table is loaded on page

```
function hideRow(checkbox)
{
    if(confirm('This action can not be recovered, are you sure you want to HIDE this Candidate? '))
    {
        checkbox.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "none";
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You could always just... not output the `<td>` in your `while()` loop? Set a `style="display: none"` on the row perhaps? Have you even thought about this?

Comment: It actually <i>can</i> be recovered because I can edit the HTML element via developer tools or firebug

Comment: i want to hide row only if user wants it so i cant use style="display: none"

Comment: Is my function didn't work?

Comment: Could you please explain more of what do you want. What different between permanently hide and remove in this case?

Comment: `while($data_set1 = mysql_fetch_array($result))` using this statement table is loaded whenever load button is clicked on My form ,so if i hide any row ones ,than 2nd time when i reload same table than that hidden row should not be shown again .

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at jQuery (http://jquery.com/) ? it is very simple to learn, and you would just do :

in your HTML header, just add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

then modify your function by

```
function hideRow(checkbox)
{
    if(confirm('This action can not be recovered, are you sure you want to HIDE this Candidate? '))
    {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: and even this query is not working ,when i click on check box and press OK button, row is not getting hide

Comment: yes, it can be done without jQuery but jQuery just makes things easier. Your initial code (with parentNode.parentNode) is heavily relying on the DOM structure, so it is likely that if and when you want to change your HTML, you will have to update your javascript. jQuery extends the life of your code by relying less on the DOM structure. Can you put a link to the code which is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

remove without jQuery

```
function hideRow(checkbox)
{
    if(confirm('This action can not be recovered, are you sure you want to HIDE this Candidate? '))
    {
        var row = checkbox.parentNode.parentNode , table = row.parentNode;
        table.removeChild(row);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: No,This is also hiding row only temporary ,same as before

Answer (score 0):

You are temporarily hiding the row by setting the style display as none. Your question is once the row is hidden, then it should not appear again when reload operation is done.

So in order to hide the row permanently, you have delete the corresponding user record from the database itself. If removed in the database then you will not be able to fetch same record from the database, so the row will not displayed when reloading the page.

Hope this suggestion works for you.